# Selenium - isElementPresent returns true but unable to click the element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario to click on 'X' icon from an overlay. When I check for the element using **selenium.isElementPresent("//img[@src='close.jpg']")**; it is returning true. But when I perform **selenium.click("//img[contains(@src,'close.jpg')]")**; action it throws an exception "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

Tried with all types of xpath but couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Which browser are you using. I know this problem from IE. Does it work out in Firefox?

Comment: I am facing the problem in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all try using couple of methods:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By selector)
   {
       return driver.findElements(selector).size()>0;
   }

    public boolean isElementVisible(By selector){
        return driver.findElement(selector).isDisplayed();
    }
```

then if your page not compeltely rendered try using some wait mechanisms:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);


driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and ***fluentWait*** mechanism:
.

```
  public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
            Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
            WebElement foo = wait.until(
                    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                            return driver.findElement(locator);
                        }
                    }
            );
            return  foo;              }     ;
    fluentWait(By.xpath(..blablabla...)).click();
```

you can also make jsCode injection:
1) if jQuery is supported

```
String cssSelector="blablabla";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

2) locating needed element through DOM model:
e.g.

```
String js="document.getElementsByTagName('div')[34].click();"
jsCodeExecution(js);
public void jsCodeExecution(String jsCode){
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(jsCode);
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

try also debug step by step to see exactly where the problem is.
Hope it helps you.

Moreover, I recommend you to verify your found css selectors and xpath verify in firepath (addon to firebug in firefox):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Using the jQuery solution I am able to resolve the issue but one more issue is that the cssSelector value is dynamic. I tried using xpath in that case but of no use and just to mention no error message is displayed. Please let me know if we can handle css which is dynamic.

Comment: well. Could you clarify what you mention saying cssSelector value is dynamic?
As far as I can see from your question - css selector of your element is   String cssSelector="img[src='close.jpg']"    and this css selector rigorously defines your web element.